# Fatal error: hugetlbfs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, huge-pages

I'm trying to find value of huge page size using `gethugepagesize()` function. I found out that `hugetlbfs.h` library has to be included. When I included the header I got compile error:

```
Fatal error: hugetlbfs.h: No such file or directory
```

When I skip including library file and call the function, I get linker error as

```
undefined reference to `gethugepagesize'
```

I looked through the post [How to get the value of huge page size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17225200/608639). I couldn't get the solution of the post working.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get linker error as "undefined reference to `gethugepagesize'" ... Am I missing something?

According to `dnf`, *`libhugetlbfs`* is *not* provided by Fedora 31.

```sh
$ dnf provides 'hugetlbfs.h'
Error: No Matches found
$ dnf provides libhugetlbfs
Error: No Matches found
```

It looks like you may need to download *`libhugetlbfs`* from their repo for Fedora. The old repo is at Sourceforge. The new repo is at [GitHub | libhugetlbfs](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs).

According to `apt-file`, *`libhugetlbfs`* is provided by Ubuntu 18. For Ubuntu the header file appears to be part of kernel headers. It looks like the library is part of the `libhugetlbfs-dev` package on Ubuntu.

```sh
$ apt-file find hugetlbfs.h
libhugetlbfs-dev: /usr/include/hugetlbfs.h
linux-headers-4.15.0-1050-oem: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1050-oem/include/config/hugetlbfs.h
linux-headers-4.15.0-1059-oem: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1059-oem/include/config/hugetlbfs.h
linux-headers-4.15.0-1065-oem: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1065-oem/include/config/hugetlbfs.h
...
```

Also see [`gethugepagesizes(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gethugepagesizes) and the project's [HOWTO](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/master/HOWTO).

---

> I'm trying to find value of huge page size using gethugepagesize() function ...

From my reading of the man page, it looks like *`libhugetlbfs`* is part of a virtual file system. It may not do what you think (if you are thinking [large page sizes on x86 cpu's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_Size_Extension)). But I may be wrong since I have never used the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the  version of installed libhugetlbfs

> rpm -qa | grep -i huge
>
> libhugetlbfs-2.20-8.fc29.x86_64
> libhugetlbfs-utils-2.20-8.fc29.x86_64

Then Install the same version of libhugetlbfs dev library.

> sudo yum install libhugetlbfs-**devel**-2.20-8.fc29.x86_64